# How to typeset elementary combinatorics?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How would one typeset basic combinatorics, like variation and combination?

For example, when using `\(V'_n^k\)` for variation with repetition, `n` and `k` are not vertically aligned. Something like `\(V'\begin{smallmatrix}k\\n\end{smallmatrix}\)` comes close, but the spacing is a little to wide, and it isn't left-aligned.

So, what's the best or usual way to do this? (Preferably also working with MathJax.)

Comment: Have you tried `\({V'}_n^k\)`?

Comment: Mico, thank you, that works! (I even remember thinking about it, but somehow I managed to forget about giving it a try.) Will you make that an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest the following code:

```
\( {V'}_n^k \)
```

Comment: No problem. Let's just delete our comments; you go first.